# Rank of a portioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $A$ is invertible, then how can I find a formula for the rank of

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A&0\\
B&C
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The only thing I could think was to write

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A&0\\
B&C
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
I&0\\
BA^{-1}&B
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A&0\\
0&I
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But I can not see how this can help me to find a formula for the rank of the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is invertible, you can row-reduce $A$ to the identity; the process will get you to $\begin{pmatrix} I_n & 0 \\ B & C\end{pmatrix}$. Then use the first $n$ rows to reduce $B$ to the $0$ matrix; you'll get $\begin{pmatrix} I_n & 0 \\ 0 & C \end{pmatrix}$. Now row-reduce $C$ and find a formula for the rank of the initial matrix in terms of the rank of the matrix $C$.

What I described above is equivalent to 
$$\begin{pmatrix} A^{-1} & 0 \\ -BA^{-1} & I_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ B & C\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} I_n & 0 \\ 0 & C\end{pmatrix}$$

Since the leftmost matrix is invertible, the initial matrix and the right-hand side have the same rank.